# How IDE "learns" my code with logic and structure?

Tags: compilation, ide, lexical-analysis

Once I use an IDE to compile my C++ code, this IDE seems know everything of my code: 
I could find the most original definition of any element in my code, no matter how deep it is from usage to definition.

The IDE seems know:

1. my code logic
2. my code structure

How IDE could do this?

Answer (score 0):

For example, it scans files to find all symbols declarations, their membership in scopes, other symbols (classes, structs and so on). Then if it find a reference to the symbol, it already knows, where it is declared. Internally, IDE uses graph models to represent the tree of dependencies and calls. If you're interested in this topic, I recommend you to read this book: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers%3a_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)

Comment: yes, I'm trying to get these "symbol" kind of information from a compilation like a IDE does. Also I want to get the "structure" information. So I guess I could imitate what IDE does here.